# Integrate Apache Solr to Drupal Core Search Module's Form

Tags: 7, views, search

The reason I am trying to link search form with a Apache Solr view is because, I have some fields to be displayed along with the results.

IF the default Apache solr is used the results does not have all the indexed fields, So I decided to create a apache solr view, but this will have the search field as a view filter and  I am unable to place the search box on the header region.

After trying all these options I though I would need to link the current search with the apache solr view.

The core reason of this question is to display few fields along with the apache solr search results.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see an actual question here.

Comment: Hi, my question here is, How to link/connect drupal search form to work with apache solr views?